# How can you implement a C callable from Numba for efficient integration with nquad?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba

I need to do a numerical integration in 6D in python. Because the scipy.integrate.nquad function is slow I am currently trying to speed things up by defining the integrand as a scipy.LowLevelCallable with Numba.

I was able to do this in 1D with the scipy.integrate.quad by replicating the example given [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.34.0/user/cfunc.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cfunc
from scipy import integrate

def integrand(t):
    return np.exp(-t) / t**2

nb_integrand = cfunc("float64(float64)")(integrand)

# regular integration
%timeit integrate.quad(integrand, 1, np.inf)
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop

```
# integration with compiled function
%timeit integrate.quad(nb_integrand.ctypes, 1, np.inf)
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 7.08 µs per loop

When I want to do this now with nquad, the nquad documentation says:

> If the user desires improved integration performance, then f may be a
>   scipy.LowLevelCallable with one of the signatures:
>
> ```
> double func(int n, double *xx)
> double func(int n, double *xx, void *user_data)
> ```
>
> where n is the number of extra parameters and args is an array of
>   doubles of the additional parameters, the xx array contains the
>   coordinates. The user_data is the data contained in the
>   scipy.LowLevelCallable.

But the following code gives me an error:

```
from numba import cfunc
import ctypes

def func(n_arg,x):
    xe = x[0]
    xh = x[1]
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*xe)*np.sin(2*np.pi*xh)

nb_func = cfunc("float64(int64,CPointer(float64))")(func)

integrate.nquad(nb_func.ctypes, [[0,1],[0,1]], full_output=True)
```

error: quad: first argument is a ctypes function pointer with incorrect signature

Is it possible to compile a function with numba that can be used with nquad directly in the code and without defining the function in an external file?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the function in a [`scipy.LowLevelCallable`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.LowLevelCallable.html) makes `nquad` happy:

```
si.nquad(sp.LowLevelCallable(nb_func.ctypes), [[0,1],[0,1]], full_output=True)
# (-2.3958561404687756e-19, 7.002641250699693e-15, {'neval': 1323})
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature of the function you pass to `nquad` should be `double func(int n, double *xx)`. You can create a decorator for your function `func` like so:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import numba
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable


def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)

    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1])
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def func(xe, xh):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*xe)*np.sin(2*np.pi*xh)

print(si.nquad(func, [[0,1],[0,1]], full_output=True))
>>>(-2.3958561404687756e-19, 7.002641250699693e-15, {'neval': 1323})
```