# Parallelize calculation of matrix elements using scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing, quad

I have to evaluate every element of a matrix using a function with a numerical integral (scipy.integrate.quad). The elements of the matrix are pixels of a 5202x3465 gray image.
I have access to a GPU and I would like to evaluate as many elements as possible in parallel, because right now, with linear programming, the entire computation takes more than 24 hours.
Here it's the sample code:

```
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, columns):
        img[i, j] = myFun(constant_args, i, j)

def myFunc(constant_args, i, j):
    new_pixel = quad(integrand, constant_args, i, j)
    ... other calculations ... 
    return new_pixel
```

I tried to use multiprocessing (as mp) like this:

```
arows = list(range(0, rows))
acolumns = list(range(0, columns))
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    img = pool.map(myFunc, (constant_args, arows, acolumns))
```

or with img = pool.map(myFunc(constant_args), (arows, acolumns))
but it gives me:
TypeError: myFunc() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'j' and 'i'

I don't understand how this works from other examples and I don't know the terminology used in the documentation.
I only want to divide that nested loop into subthreads, if someone suggests a different approach I'm all ears.
ps. I tried with numba but it gives errors when interacting with some Scipy libraries

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Normally the first step is to speed up the integration. Can you provide a full working example of at least the integration? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45823212/4045774

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with this (for free of course) but would need access to the code you are trying to optimise.  Feel free to reach out to me on twitter if you want to take it further https://twitter.com/walkingrandomly

Answer (score 0):

First the error is in your call to the `map`- operation. It would have to be:

```
arows = list(range(0, rows))
acolumns = list(range(0, columns))
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    img = pool.map(myFunc, constant_args, arows, acolumns)
```

However, this might not result in what you are looking for as this just runs through the 3 arguments (which have to be lists). It is not running through combinations of them, especially `arows` and `acolumns`. For example, if `constant_args` has 3 elements, `Pool.map` would stop after 3 iterations without running through the longer lists `arows` or `acolumns`.

First you should make all combinations of rows and column indices

```
from itertools import product, repeat
comb = list(product(arows, acolumns))
```

That procudes something like (all possible combinations)

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Next I would zip these combinations with your `constant_args`

```
constant_args = [10, 11]
arguments = list(zip(comb , repeat(constant_args)))
```

It produces a list of tuples with each tuple containing two elements. The first is your pixel position and the second are your `constant_args`

```
[((1, 1), [10, 11]),
 ((1, 2), [10, 11]),
 ((1, 3), [10, 11]),
 ((2, 1), [10, 11]),
 ((2, 2), [10, 11]),
 ((2, 3), [10, 11]),
 ((3, 1), [10, 11]),
 ((3, 2), [10, 11]),
 ((3, 3), [10, 11])]
```

Now we have to modify your `myFunc`somewhat:

```
def myFunc(pix_id, constant_args):
    new_pixel = quad(integrand, constant_args, pix_id[0], pix_id[1])
    ... other calculations ... 
    return new_pixel
```

Finally, we use Pool.starmap to work the magic (see here: [starmap usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443941/4141279)):

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    img = pool.starmap(myFunc, arguments )
```

What happens is that `starmap` takes a list of tuples and provides these as inputs for the functions. However, `starmap` automatically unpacks the list of tuples into single arguments for your funtion. The first argument is `pix_id` consisting of two elements and the second argument is `constant_args`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (one of my projects). It does *vectorized* computation, so this will run very fast.
Example with an output of shape 2x2:

```py
import quadpy


def f(x):
    return [[x ** 2, x**3], [x**4, x**5]]


val, err = quadpy.quad(f, 0, 1)
print(val)
```

```
[[0.33333333 0.25      ]
 [0.2        0.16666667]]
```

The output of `f` must be of shape `(..., x.shape)`, and the `...` can be any tuple, e.g., `(5202, 3465)`.