# Passing arguments to scipy.LowLevelCallable while using functions in C

Tags: python, scipy, cython, numerical-integration

I am trying to use C defined function for numerical integration in SciPy. The example case given 
[here (SciPy documentation)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#quad-callbacks) works fine.

In my case, the `testlib.c` file is

```
/* testlib.c */

#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

double factor(double phi, double r) {
    double val = (2*PI)/(pow(r, 2) + 3*cos(phi));
    return val;
}

//------------------------------------

double f2(int n, double *x, void *user_data) {
    double c = *(double *)user_data;
    double v1 = factor(c, 0.25); // value of phi defined inline but it is an argument
    return v1 + x[0] - x[1] ; /* corresponds to v1 + x - y    */
}
```

And, the test.py function calling the `testlib.so` file obtained after compilation is below,

```
import os, ctypes
from scipy import integrate, LowLevelCallable

lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('testlib.so'))

# define return type in .restype
lib.f2.restype = ctypes.c_double

# define argument type in .argtypes
lib.f2.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_void_p)

# additional argument, here a constant, casting needed
c = ctypes.c_double(1.0)
user_data = ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(c), ctypes.c_void_p)

# pass extra argument
func = LowLevelCallable(lib.f2, user_data)

# quadrature in 3-dimensions
out=integrate.nquad(func, [[0, 10], [-10, 0]])

print(out)

# -----------------------------------------------
phi = 0.25   #  How to pass these to the C function 
esv = 1.25   
cv1 = 0.03   
cv2 = -0.15  
cv3 = 3.0
```

---

**My question**: How to pass additional arguments such as `c` to the function `f2`. In my case I have 5 such arguments, available as `np.float64` in the calling py file.

I wonder if I can pass the arguments as array as `user_data` to the function `f2` .

- From [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad) for `nquad`, found that arguments are to be passed as array and `int n` in the C function is the number of arguments passed.
- Also, I'm Open to try other options such as cython, pyCapsule but no experience there in. Found very similar question using numba and jit, where no additional arguments are passed. [Using numba and jit for integration: SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823212/how-can-you-implement-a-c-callable-from-numba-for-efficient-integration-with-nqu)

---

For compiling `testlib.c`: `$   gcc -shared -fPIC -o testlib.so testlib.c`

Comment: Btw, you probably should compile testlib.so with optimization on (i.e `-O2` or `-O3` or whatever best) to get best performance.

Comment: As long as you only pass scalars dtype np.float64 There is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60619681/4045774, which shows how to do this using Numba. You can pass the additional params as args, as you would do in pure Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are more than one way to skin the cat, but if your are using `ctypes` there is possibility to stick with `ctypes`, for example:

You can create an array an initialize it with values, e.g.:

```
ptr_to_buffer=(ctypes.c_double*5)(phi,esv,cv1,cv2,cv3)
user_data = ctypes.cast(ptr_to_buffer, ctypes.c_void_p)
```

or if the data is already in a numpy-array (as I originally understood your question):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], np.float64)

import ctypes
ptr_to_buffer=(ctypes.c_double*5).from_buffer(a)
user_data = ctypes.cast(ptr_to_buffer, ctypes.c_void_p)
```

in this case `user_data` is a copy of a and doesn't share the memory, which is sometimes a good thing and sometimes not.

For bigger arrays one can also let `user_data` also to share the memory with the numpy-array:

```
user_data = ctypes.c_void_p(a.__array_interface__['data'][0])
```

as can be verified via:

```
ctypes.cast(user_data, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))[0] = 42.0
print(a[0])
# 42.0 and not 1.0
```

For this variant you actually have to check, that the memory of the numpy-array is contiguous, for an example how this information can be obtained cab be looked up for example in [`numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b7c27bd2a3817f59c84b004b87bba5db57d9a9b0/numpy/ctypeslib.py#L524).

Maybe a less low-level way of obtaining the pointer is

```
user_data =  ctypes.cast(np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(a), ctypes.c_void_p)
```

but still checks of the shape/strides are needed.